# Icon on ui tabs (validate)

Tags: user-interface, jquery-validate, icons, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to add an icon on ui tabs when validate fails.

Which method should i use (option is my guess).

Can anyone help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about have transparent or hidden icons (e.g. using `background-image`) to all tabs by default.
Use the validator to change the icon via css/class rather than adding/removing?